# How make github to ignore whitespaces/newlines

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I'm running a team of developers on a project and I constantly see this kind of commits:

[image: img]

Whenever I get about 5000 lines of code like this, i get quite frustrated

Is there any way to make github not show added whitespaces/newlines?

Answer (score 2):

Set the URL parameter [**`w=1`**](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets) in the github url which enables the **ignore whitepsace feature**

Take a look at the difference between

[https://github.com/renelink/..../9491a0ed3ae57f7b33386605d3f62f85eca8ae05](https://github.com/renelink/github_feature_sandbox/commit/9491a0ed3ae57f7b33386605d3f62f85eca8ae05)

and

[https://github.com/renelink/..../9491a0ed3ae57f7b33386605d3f62f85eca8ae05?w=1](https://github.com/renelink/github_feature_sandbox/commit/9491a0ed3ae57f7b33386605d3f62f85eca8ae05?w=1)

---

But I guess the main problem is that the developers work on different OS and do not configure [core.autocrlf](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace).